# Highchart line chart with category do not occupy full width

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highchart to generate a line chart with data labels. Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {
        text: 'Chart without categories'
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['a','b'],
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1,2]
    }]
});
```

This code generates the following chart: As you can see, there is a space between the line and and the borders of the chart.

[image: chart with categories]

Without using categories, there is no space:
[image: chart without categories]

What can I do to remove this spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a default behavior of `category` axis type. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wuqxb2cy/ with a more visible distribution into categories.

As a solution you can set `xAxis.tickmarkPlacement` and `series.pointPlacement` to `'on'`:

```
xAxis: {
    categories: [...],
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
},
series: [{
    data: [...],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qkezc3mx/

**API Refefence:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickmarkPlacement

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointPlacement